# error: [Errno 111] Connection refused - Python, Selenium

Tags: python, sockets, selenium, selenium-ide

I am learning to use Selenium. So far, I succeeded in getting it to work. So, now I wanted to record navigation sequences using Selenium IDE, export them to python and run them.

This is the code I used.

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re
#from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

class rc(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.verificationErrors = []
    #self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
    #self.display.start()
    self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.some-website.in")
    self.selenium.start()

def test_rc(self):
    sel = self.selenium
    sel.click("link=Careers")
    response = sel.get_title()
    print response

def tearDown(self):
    self.selenium.stop()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
    #self.display.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The commented lines are manually added and were tried in case they worked (as they did in the previous basic example in which I just wanted selenium to work and resolve dependencies).

On running this auto-generated python code, I get:

```
File "mytest_test.py", line 34, in setUp
  self.selenium.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 202, in start
  result = self.get_string("getNewBrowserSession", start_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 237, in get_string
  result = self.do_command(verb, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 226, in do_command
  conn.request("POST", "/selenium-server/driver/", body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
  self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
  self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
  raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You converted test script for selenium RC, so make sure that selenium RC server is running at your machine before executing test script.

User below command to run selenium server:
open command prompt and go to downloaded selenium server jar file and run command

> > java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was with **incompatible version of Chrome and chromedriver**

check following commands in your terminal:

```
cd <<your test folder>>
which chromedriver
chromedriver --version
```

and compare the version with the **latest version** of chromedriver:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Answer (score 0):

When you face such an issue, check your `geckodriver` setup.

When you open a browser, your marionette driver code should be commented like this: `#cap['marionette'] = True`.

Don't enable the marionette driver for Linux.